# InnoDB monitor output unclear, foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, output, innodb

I have two database tables, InnoDB, both have a column `id_fornitore`, there's no way to create a foreign key and i don't understand why. It's a simple foreign key, and I have succesfully created other on the same table.
Here is my query:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_prima_nota
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id_fornitore
FOREIGN KEY (id_fornitore) REFERENCES tbl_fornitori(id_fornitore)
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Here is the database status monitor output:

```
Foreign key constraint fails for table `fatturazione2`.`#sql-68_409`:
,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_id_fornitore` FOREIGN KEY (`id_fornitore`) REFERENCES `tbl_fornitori` (`id_fornitore`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
Trying to add in child table, in index fk_id_fornitore tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
0: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

But in parent table `fatturazione2`.`tbl_fornitori`, in index  uk_id_fornitore,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
```

Anybody can understand what's going on here? Many thanks.

**UPDATE**
thanks to [Bill Karwin](http:///users/20860/bill-karwin) for the query, and [Rick James](http:///users/1766831/rick-james) to point me in the right direction. The problem was: when i first added the column `id_fornitore` to the table `tbl_prima_nota` I allowed `NULL` as a possible value, but i didn't choose it as `Default`; on column creation, since the table was already populated, MySQL added `0` as default value in each row, but `0` is differen from `NULL`. As a quick solution, sice the column `id_fornitore` was empty, I deleted it from `tbl_prima_nota` and I recreated with `NULL` as default value, and than I could create the foreign key without problems.

Comment: Verify that tbl_fornitori(id_fornitore) exists for all rows in tbl_prima_nota.  I think you will find some violations.

Comment: Yes, there was a problem, please read my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every value in the child table's foreign key must reference a corresponding value in the parent table's primary or unique key.

You can't create a foreign key on column `tbl_prima_nota.id_fornitore` because that column contains some values that are missing in the referenced `tbl_fornitori.id_fornitore`.

You can query the rows in the child table whose foreign key values are missing in the parent table:

```
SELECT pn.*
FROM tbl_prima_nota AS pn
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_fornitori AS f USING (id_fornitore)
WHERE f.id_fornitore IS NULL;
```

You must either add rows to `tbl_fornitori` with the missing values, or else delete the rows from `tbl_prima_nota`, or update those rows to change the value in the foreign key column.